# Why am I receiving a 'Fatal Error: Class 'Stripe_Customer' not found' when I attempt to create a customer object?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Whenever I attempt to create my customer object, I am presented with this error. I have tried including file paths to my `Stripe` library, but I might be pointing to the incorrect path. Portion of my script where error occurs:

```
function checkout()
    { 
        error_reporting(E_ALL); 
        $success = '';
        $error = '';

        if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $conn = dbconnection();
        $stripeToken = $_POST["stripeToken"];
        $random_id2 = $_POST["random_id2"];
        $userid = get_current_user_id();

        require_once('Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');              

        $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
            "source" => $stripeToken,
            "description" => "Customer")
        );
```

Comment: Why not 1) try adding `__DIR__` to your path and 2) use `is_file()` before you include it. It will at least tell you if it's where you think it is

Comment: Also you may want to try *Composer* (I believe it has a reliable autoloader) or create your own `spl_autoload_register()` to auto load classes.

Comment: Finally, you may be including a file that exists but that file may not contain that particular class. Just search the files for that class and method, then you'll know what file to include.

Comment: @Rasclatt I have included the path to the Customer.php file with the class and I receive the 'Stripe_ApiResource' not found error

Comment: Did you include the `__DIR__` as part of your path?

Comment: Also Stripe uses a namespace it looks like so you may have to use the namespace: `\Stripe\Customer::create(etc...`, although further reading says what you have is a legacy

Comment: @Rasclatt Yeah I've tried it utilizing the namespace. It was still giving me a 'class not found' error. Would this be the correct way to include __DIR__ ? require_once(__DIR__ .'Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');

Comment: `__DIR__`, not `DIR`. And, you need a directory separator and possibly some backing out paths. Note that `__DIR__` is the folder where the file (the function you are calling the class in) resides. I don't know where your files are stored, so I can't tell you how to include files.

Comment: @Rasclatt Yeah apologies. Stack auto changed it to DIR. Anyway, I've figured it out. I included the path to stripe.php using "require" instead of "require_once".